# Me sale error de FK al llenar una BD de registros en SQL Server, una BD creada por scripts

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, script

Al crear esta BD de Empleados y Departamentos:

```
-- Creación de la tabla Departamento
CREATE TABLE Departamento (
codDepto varchar (4) PRIMARY KEY,
nombreDpto varchar (20) NOT NULL,
ciudad varchar (15),
codDirector varchar (12)
);
-- Creación de la tabla Empleado
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Empleado;
CREATE TABLE Empleado (
nDIEmp VARCHAR( 12 ) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
nomEmp VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
sexEmp CHAR( 1 ) NOT NULL CHECK (sexEmp IN ('F', 'M') ),
fecNac DATE NOT NULL ,
fecIncorporacion DATE NOT NULL,
salEmp FLOAT NOT NULL,
comisionE FLOAT NOT NULL,
cargoE VARCHAR( 15 ) NOT NULL,
jefeID VARCHAR( 12 ),
codDepto VARCHAR( 4 ) NOT NULL,
-- Declaración de las llaves foráneas
CONSTRAINT FK_Empl FOREIGN KEY (jefeID) REFERENCES Empleado,
CONSTRAINT FK_Dpto FOREIGN KEY (codDepto) REFERENCES Departamento
);

ALTER TABLE Departamento
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EmpDir
FOREIGN KEY (codDirector) REFERENCES Empleado;
```

Despues de crearse exitosamente, procedo a llenar de registros

```
INSERT INTO Departamento (codDepto, nombreDpto, ciudad, coddirector) VALUES
('1000', 'GERENCIA', 'CALI', '31.840.269'),
('1500', 'PRODUCCIÓN', 'CALI', '16.211.383'),
('2000', 'VENTAS', 'CALI', '31.178.144'),
('3000', 'INVESTIGACIÓN', 'CALI', '16.759.060'),
('3500', 'MERCADEO', 'CALI', '22.222.222'),
('2100', 'VENTAS', 'POPAYAN', '31.751.219'),
('2200', 'VENTAS', 'BUGA', '768.782'),
('2300', 'VENTAS', 'CARTAGO', '737.689'),
('4000', 'MANTENIMIENTO', 'CALI', '333.333.333'),
('4100', 'MANTENIMIENTO', 'POPAYAN', '888.888'),
('4200', 'MANTENIMIENTO', 'BUGA', '11.111.111'),
('4300', 'MANTENIMIENTO', 'CARTAGO', '444.444');

INSERT INTO Empleado (nDIEmp, nomEmp, sexEmp, fecNac, fecIncorporacion, salEmp,
comisionE, cargoE, jefeID, codDepto)
VALUES
('31.840.269', 'María Rojas', 'F', '1959-01-15', '16-05-1990', 6250000, 1500000, 'Gerente', NULL, '1000'),
('16.211.383', 'Luis Pérez', 'M', '1956-02-25', '2000-01-01', 5050000, 0, 'Director', '31.840.269', '1500'),
('31.178.144', 'Rosa Angulo', 'F', '1957-03-15', '1998-08-16', 3250000, 3500000, 'Jefe Ventas', '31.840.269', '2000'),
('16.759.060', 'Darío Casas', 'M', '1960-04-05', '1992-11-01', 4500000, 500000, 'Investigador', '31.840.269', '3000'),
('22.222.222', 'Carla López', 'F', '1975-05-11', '2005-07-16', 4500000, 500000, 'Jefe Mercadeo', '31.840.269', '3500'),
('22.222.333', 'Carlos Rozo', 'M', '1975-05-11', '2001-09-16', 750000, 500000, 'Vigilante', '31.840.269', '3500') ,
('1.751.219', 'Melissa Roa', 'F', '1960-06-19', '2001-03-16', 2250000, 2500000, 'Vendedor', '31.178.144', '2100'),
('768.782', 'Joaquín Rosas', 'M', '1947-07-07', '1990-05-16', 2250000, 2500000, 'Vendedor', '31.178.144', '2200'),
('737.689', 'Mario Llano', 'M', '1945-08-30', '1990-05-16', 2250000, 2500000, 'Vendedor', '31.178.144', '2300'),
```

Hay mas registros para Empleado.

Sale estos errores: Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_EmpDir". The conflict occurred in database "Empresa", table "dbo.Empleado", column 'nDIEmp'.

Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Dpto". The conflict occurred in database "Empresa", table "dbo.Departamento", column 'codDepto'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te has creado una dependencia circular entre las tablas.
Un departamento tiene que tener un director y un empleado tiene que estar asociado a un departamento.

¿Qué pasa cuando la base de datos está vacía e intentamos insertar el primer departamento? Que no podemos porque no existe el empleado al que queremos hacer referencia.

```
INSERT INTO Departamento (codDepto, nombreDpto, ciudad, coddirector) VALUES
('1000', 'GERENCIA', 'CALI', '31.840.269');
```

¿Cómo podemos saltarnos temporalmente las restricciones que nosotros mismos hemos impuesto para hacer una primera carga de datos? Deshabilitando momentáneamente las restricciones, insertando los datos a continuación y volviéndolas a habilitar.

¿Cómo se deshabilitan y vuelven a habilitar las restricciones? Pues basándome en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/159064/2553194) de StackOverflow en tu caso sería

```
-- Deshabilitar restricciones
ALTER TABLE Departamento NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
ALTER TABLE Empleado NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;

-- Habilitar restricciones una vez hemos hecho los INSERT
ALTER TABLE Departamento WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
ALTER TABLE Empleado WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
```

En [este fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=69dfaf807def22c3f10ec61d28c69e43) he lanzado un juego reducido de tus insert intercalando las instrucciones de arriba y puedes ver que funciona correctamente.

Si algún departamento tiene un código de empleado que no existe o un empleado se asocia a un departamento que no existe, se producirá un error al intentar ejecutar estos últimos ALTER porque tu juego de datos no cumple las restricciones. Tenlo en cuenta.

BONUS:
Este INSERT me ha dado error por el formato de la segunda fecha

```
INSERT INTO Empleado (nDIEmp, nomEmp, sexEmp, fecNac, fecIncorporacion, salEmp,
comisionE, cargoE, jefeID, codDepto)
VALUES
('31.840.269', 'María Rojas', 'F', '1959-01-15', '16-05-1990', 6250000, 1500000, 'Gerente', NULL, '1000');
```

Cambiándolo por este se ejecuta correctamente

```
INSERT INTO Empleado (nDIEmp, nomEmp, sexEmp, fecNac, fecIncorporacion, salEmp,
comisionE, cargoE, jefeID, codDepto)
VALUES
('31.840.269', 'María Rojas', 'F', '1959-01-15', '1990-05-16', 6250000, 1500000, 'Gerente', NULL, '1000');
```

Comment: Gracias bro, me salvaste